# Убрать весь текст кроме числа

Tags: php, ulogin

Всем доброе время суток.

uLogin в переменной $user['identity'] выводит полную ссылку на страницу http://vk.com/id00000000, однако так как я пишу модуль интеграции приложения с сайтом, мне нужны только цифры. Отсюда вопрос. Как можно удалить все буквы/символы (:, /) и оставить только цифры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = preg_replace("/[^\d]/","", $src);
```

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на страницу https://ulogin.ru/help.php#fields

`identity` - это уникальный идентификатор в рамках ulogin (всех соцсетей). В этом поле могут быть, по большому счету, любые данные, хоть md5-хеш.

`profile` - ссылка на профиль пользователя. Так что, если уж парсить, то его.

`uid` - **уникальный идентификатор пользователя в рамках соцсети**. Почему бы вам не использовать именно его? И ничего preg_replace'ить не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
$src = 'http://vk.com/id00000000';
preg_match('~\d+~', $src, $m);
if (isset($m[0])) {
    $id = $m[0];
}
```

2.

```
$src = 'http://vk.com/id00000000';
$pos = strpos($src, 'id');
if ($pos !== false) {
    $id = substr($src, $pos + 2);
}
```